# Set up WatchKit Table

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, watchkit

I'm trying to load my data into a `WatchKit` table. Basically, set the text of the `match` label in each table group cell with the array of `match`s I have.

I've got the data, and everything set up, but actually loading it **into the table is where I'm stuck**.

**`InterfaceController`.swift**:

```
    var receivedData = Array<Dictionary<String, String>>()

    var eventsListSO = Array<Event>()

    @IBOutlet var rowTable: WKInterfaceTable!

    func doTable() {

        eventsListSO = Event.eventsListFromValues(receivedData)
        rowTable.setNumberOfRows(eventsListSO.count, withRowType: "rows")

        for var i = 0; i < self.rowTable.numberOfRows; i++ {
            let row = rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as? TableRowController
            for eventm in eventsListSO {
                row!.mLabel.setText(eventm.eventMatch)
                NSLog("SetupTableM: %@", eventm.eventMatch)
            }
        }

    }
```

I was trying to do it in `doTable` because that seemed like best place to do this, and I think `doTable` is set up right, but I'm not sure?  Not sure if I need to make the array an optional type or what.

*Here is the referencing code if needed:*

**`RowController`.swift**:

```
class TableRowController {

    @IBOutlet var mLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var cGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!

}
```

**`Event`.swift**:

```
class Event {

    var eventTColor:String
    var eventMatch:String

    init(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) {
        eventTColor = dataDictionary["TColor"]!
        eventMatch = dataDictionary["Match"]!
    }

    class func newEvent(dataDictionary:Dictionary<String,String>) -> Event {
        return Event(dataDictionary: dataDictionary)
    }

    class func eventsListFromValues(values: Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> Array<Event> {
        var array = Array<Event>()

        for eventValues in values {
            let event = Event(dataDictionary: eventValues)
            array.append(event)
        }

        return array
    }

}
```

So I'm not sure if:

**- `doTable` is set up right (can't be because `eventsListSO.count` is null)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you work with tables in WatchKit is a lot different than UIKit.

After you call `setNumberOfRows` you need to iterate over each row and get the `RowController`.

```
for var i = 0; i < self.rowTable.numberOfRows; i++ {
    var row = self.rowTable.rowControllerAtIndex(i)
    //setup row here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yeah that makes sense, and when I was trying to finish that code out, I would get an error with the things I was trying.  I put an edit in my question above to show you what I am trying and what line I'm getting an error on.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `if let row = self.rowTable.rowAtIndex(i) as? RowController { //setup in here }`

Comment: Updated my code per your suggestion.  Any thoughts on if my setup looks right and where the best place to call the setup is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check Raywenderlich's tutorial about WatchKit: http://www.raywenderlich.com/96741/watchkit-tutorial-with-swift-tables-glances-and-handoff, it teach you how to show tables on your watch, hope this help!

Comment: Yeah I've seen that, any ideas on how to help me with my specific implementation?